# Faster Way to Categorize Unique Row Combinations based on a Condition in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, vectorization

I have a dataset that has the same layout as the one below. I want to categorize where each person went in their car for a given month.

| Date | Visitor | Car Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6-2022 | Michael | Chrysler | Work |
| 6-2022 | Jim | Subaru | Home |
| 6-2022 | Jim | Subaru | Work |
| 6-2022 | Michael | Chrysler | Karate |
| 7-2022 | Michael | Chrysler | Work |
| 7-2022 | Jim | Subaru | Home |
| 7-2022 | Jim | Subaru | Work |

The solution would look something like this:

| Date | Visitor | Car Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6-2022 | Michael | Chrysler | Work & Karate |
| 6-2022 | Jim | Subaru | Work & Home |
| 7-2022 | Michael | Chrysler | Work |
| 7-2022 | Jim | Subaru | Work & Home |

I HAVE a solution but it scales linearly with time as the number of rows increases. The fastest I have gotten it to run over ~32,000 rows is ~15 minutes.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the data in your solution `df` relates to the input: for "6-2022" with "Michael", your solution has "Chrysler" and "Work, Home & Karate", but he went to "Karate" in a "Subaru", and looks like he never went home in either month. Likewise, "Jim" didn't reach "Work" in "7-2022".

Comment: @ouroboros1 thanks for the input, corrected the solution df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as follows:

- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Date, Visitor, Car Name`, and apply [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to the values of `Location`.
- To change the last `,` delimiter to an ampersand, you could use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with a regex pattern.

```
res = df.groupby(['Date','Visitor','Car Name'], 
                 as_index=False, sort=False)['Location'].agg(', '.join)

# changing each last `,` delimiter into an `&`
res['Location'] = res['Location'].replace(r',\s(?=[^,]*$)',' & ', regex=True)

print(res)

     Date  Visitor  Car Name       Location
0  6-2022  Michael  Chrysler  Work & Karate
1  6-2022      Jim    Subaru    Home & Work
2  7-2022  Michael  Chrysler           Work
3  7-2022      Jim    Subaru    Home & Work
```

If you expect duplicates per group (and want to get rid of them), you could use `.agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)))` instead of `.agg(', '.join)`. Mind you, this will affect the order, not sure if this is a problem. If so, there are of course also ways to get rid of duplicates in a list, while maintained order.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Visitor', 'Car Name'], as_index=False)['Location'].agg(' & '.join)
```

Output:

```
     Date  Visitor  Car Name       Location
0  6-2022      Jim    Subaru    Home & Work
1  6-2022  Michael  Chrysler  Work & Karate
2  7-2022      Jim    Subaru    Home & Work
3  7-2022  Michael  Chrysler           Work
```